# How do I get tooltips of stock charts to be rendered in "separated" display mode in anychart?

Tags: anychart

I have implemented a candlestick chart with a bunch of line charts showing tooltips in "union" display mode. (anychart + Next.js)

But I can't figure out how to get tooltips to be rendered in "separate" mode.
Part of code below:

```js
  const [ma, setMa] = useState([])

  const table = anychart.data.table()
  table.addData(dStock)

  const mapping = table.mapAs()
  mapping.addField(`open`, 1)
  mapping.addField(`high`, 2)
  mapping.addField(`low`, 3)
  mapping.addField(`close`, 4)

  const chart = anychart.stock()
  const ticker = `サンプル`

  const tooltip = chart.tooltip()
  // tooltip.displayMode(`separated`) // if I add this line, no tooltips show up
  tooltip.titleFormat(ticker)

  const series = chart.plot(0).candlestick(mapping)
  series.name(ticker)
  series.tooltip().format(`\n始値：{%open}\n高値：{%high}\n安値：{%low}\n終値：{%close}`)

  const s = []
  
  if (ma.length > 0) {
    ma.forEach((v, k) => {
      const key = Object.keys(v)[0]
      s[k] = chart.plot(0).line(v[key])
      s[k].name(key)
      s[k].tooltip().format(`{%seriesName}: {%value}`)
    })
  }
```

Charts with tooltips in union mode:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, the current version of the library doesn't support separated mode for the Stock chart tooltip. Union and single modes are supported only at the moment. We will take this requirement into account for future updates.